# Flex - Advisable to use multiple web services?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, actionscript-3, air

I am developing an application with multiple windows, all using their own web services.

Is it bad practice to use more than one web service per application? If so, what are the disadvantages?

Comment: Could you please specify what do you mean «all windows using their own web services?» Are they using web services from different sources (servers)? Are you using (SOAP ?) web service right from flex app via WebService object? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to use more than
>   one web service per application?

No!  In fact, I don't think I've ever worked on an application that used only one web service.